# How to check if a Dictionary contains a given value?

Tags: vb.net

How do I check if a value exists in a `Dictionary(Of int, String)`?

Let’s say I have `[{1, 'One'};{2, 'Two'};{3, 'Three'}]`, how to check if ‘Two’ exists ?

Comment: In C# there's a ContainsValue and a ContainsKey function. Should be rather similar in VB.Net...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`ContainsValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
If myDictionary.ContainsValue("Two") Then
    debug.print("Exists")
End If
```

That’s all you need.

Comment: what if we want to check 'one' 'two' 'three' exists in dictionary. Can we use containsvalue fxn for more than one value.

Comment: @BhartiPandita honestly I don't know if a native method exist for that, but you can put your values in an Array and loop through it

Answer (score 5):

Complementing raed´s answer, you can also use [ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.8) to search for the keys instead of the values.

```
If myDictionary.ContainsKey(1) Then
    debug.print("Exists")
End If
```

This also works with *string* keys, like in the example:

```
[{"Chris", "Alive"};{"John", "Deceased"}]

If myDictionary.ContainsKey("Chris") Then
    debug.print("Chris Exists in dictionary")
End If

If myDictionary.ContainsValue("Alive") Then
    debug.print("There is someone alive in the dictionary")
End If
```