# Remove duplicates in dictionary

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have a dictionary that is populated with entities matched by a regular expression. It pulls all the data correctly except it also brings in duplicate data. How would I prevent duplicate data from coming in?

Here's my code

```
    Dim largeFilePath As String = newMasterFilePath
    Dim lines1 = File.ReadLines(largeFilePath).ToList 'don't use ReadAllLines
    Dim reg = New Regex("\<\!NOTATION.*$|\<\!ENTITY.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim entities = From line In lines1
                   Where reg.IsMatch(line)

    Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim idx = -1
    For Each s In entities
        idx = lines1.IndexOf(s, idx + 1)
        dictionary.Add(idx, s)
    Next

    Dim deletedItems = 0
    For Each itm In dictionary
        lines1.RemoveAt(itm.Key - deletedItems)
        deletedItems += 1
    Next

    For Each s In dictionary.Values
        lines1.Insert(1, s)
    Next
```

What I expect is for there to only be one entry per item.

This is the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN"[
<!ENTITY cdcs_5-35.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_5-35.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-2a.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-2A.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!NOTATION bmp SYSTEM "bmp">
<!NOTATION svg SYSTEM "svg">
<!NOTATION png SYSTEM "png">
<doc service="xs" docid="BKw46" docstat="formal" verstatpg="ver" cycle="1" chglevel="1">
<front numcols="1">
<idinfo>
<?Pub Lcl _divid="100" _parentid="0">
<tmidno>Life with Pets</tmidno>
<chgnum>Change 1</chgnum>
<chgdate>2 August 2018</chgdate>
<chghistory>
<!NOTATION bmp SYSTEM "bmp">
<!NOTATION svg SYSTEM "svg">
<!NOTATION png SYSTEM "png">
<chginfo>
<chgtxt>Change 1</chgtxt>
<date>2 August 2018</date>
</front>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-19.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-19.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_3-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_3-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_4-48.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_4-48.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<body numcols="1">
<chapter>
<title>This is chapter 1</title>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-24.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-24.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<para0>
<title>Climb the ladder immedietly</title>
<para>Retrieve the cat.</para></para0></chapter>
<chapter>
<title>Don't forget to feed the dog</title>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-24.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-24.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<para0>
<!ENTITY cdcs_4-48.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_4-48.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<title>Prep for puppies</title>
<para>Puppies are cute</para></para0>
</chapter>
</body>
</doc>
```

Thank you for helping me on this.
Max

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31472471/5162073) should be of help to you.

Comment: Do you plan to removing the matches lines first and then moving the unique values to the top?

Comment: How about modifying the linq query, thats where to start as well as all the other code can be removed...

Comment: @MuhammadAlnahrawy I was thinking it would put the values up at top then remove duplicates. Or anyway you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line `dictionary.Add(idx, s)` to be `dictionary.Add(idx, s.Trim)`

And then:

```
Dim uniqueDict = dictionary.GroupBy(Function(itm) itm.Value).
                   Select(Function(group) group.First()).
                   ToDictionary(Function(itm) itm.Key, Function(itm) itm.Value)

For Each s In uniqueDict.Values
     lines.Insert(1, s)
Next
```

The results, all duplicates removed:

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN"[
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-24.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-24.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_4-48.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_4-48.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_3-5.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_3-5.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-19.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-19.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!NOTATION png SYSTEM "png">
<!NOTATION svg SYSTEM "svg">
<!NOTATION bmp SYSTEM "bmp">
<!ENTITY cdcs_2-2a.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_2-2A.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<!ENTITY cdcs_5-35.wmf SYSTEM "graphics\CDCS_5-35.wmf" NDATA wmf>
<doc service="xs" docid="BKw46" docstat="formal" verstatpg="ver" cycle="1" chglevel="1">
<front numcols="1">
<idinfo>
<?Pub Lcl _divid="100" _parentid="0">
<tmidno>Life with Pets</tmidno>
<chgnum>Change 1</chgnum>
<chgdate>2 August 2018</chgdate>
<chghistory>
<chginfo>
<chgtxt>Change 1</chgtxt>
<date>2 August 2018</date>
</front>
<body numcols="1">
<chapter>
<title>This is chapter 1</title>
<para0>
<title>Climb the ladder immedietly</title>
<para>Retrieve the cat.</para></para0></chapter>
<chapter>
<title>Don't forget to feed the dog</title>
<para0>
<title>Prep for puppies</title>
<para>Puppies are cute</para></para0>
</chapter>
</body>
</doc>
```

Comment: This removed all the <!Entity except the duplicates

Comment: @MaxineHammett it worked for me and I got the expected results, did you try it with your sample text here?

Comment: I don't think I have it in the code right. Could you update your code showing where it would go in mine please

Comment: check my results please.

Comment: I believe your results. I just don't know where to put the code. Need help please

Comment: Replace this part from the old code with the whole new one:
 `For Each s In dictionary.Values
        lines1.Insert(1, s)
    Next`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191624/discussion-between-maxine-hammett-and-muhammad-alnahrawy).

Comment: Muhammed will you meet me in the chat room please

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, check for duplicate before adding:

```
For Each s In entities
    If Not dictionary.TryGetValue(lines1.IndexOf(s, idx + 1), s) Then
        idx = lines1.IndexOf(s, idx + 1)
        dictionary.Add(idx, s)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I get the error 'An item with the same key has already been added'

Comment: That's the `lines1.IndexOf(s, idx + 1)` part which isn't right. I wasn't sure how to put it right without breaking your code, so guessed a little bit. It has to be the same when you look for a duplicate and when you add an item to the collection.